# Creating virtual gamepad on Monogame

Tags: android, xamarin.android, monogame

I'm trying to re-create the sample [virtual gamepad](https://github.com/CartBlanche/MonoGame-Samples/blob/master/VirtualGamePad/Game1.cs) on Android(but will target iOS too later). But there are lots of things that are missing on the current MonoGame(3.5) like ButtonDefinition, GamePad.ButtonsDefinitions, and GamePad.LeftThumbStickDefinition.

How to create virtual/on-screen gamepad for MonoGame 3.5?